# Why can't I scroll to the end of my ListView?

Tags: java, android

I can't scroll my list view to the end. It seems to be stuck halfway at the last element(Neptune).

ListView is stuck at the last element as shown in the picture.

activity_main.xml

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <include
        layout="@layout/app_bar"
        android:id="@+id/app_bar"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/listView"
        />


    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/listView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/app_bar"
        />



</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

MainActivity.java

```
ListView listView = findViewById(R.id.listView);

String[] planetsArray = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.planet_list);

ArrayAdapter<String> arrayadapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(MainActivity.this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, planetsArray){

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent){

        View view = super.getView(position,convertView,parent);

        ViewGroup.LayoutParams layoutparams = view.getLayoutParams();

        //Define your height here.
        layoutparams.height = 300;

        view.setLayoutParams(layoutparams);

        return view;
    }
};

listView.setAdapter(arrayadapter);
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: Please post your full xml.

Comment: I have already updated my xml. @RajshreeTiwari

Comment: Is there any particular reason you are setting the height programmatically? Also the reason it's not showing everything is probably because 300 is too low, try increasing it.

Answer (score 0):

In activity_main.xml try changing android:layout_height="0dp" to android:layout_height="wrap_content", it will still be updated to the programmatically set hight of 300, but it will not be defined to 0dp, which should help with the problem.

Comment: The issue is still not resolved. The last element can't be displayed perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

change your **android:layout_height="0dp"** to  **android:layout_height="wrap_content"** 
or set layout_weight="1"

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <include
        layout="@layout/app_bar"
        android:id="@+id/app_bar"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/listView"
        />


    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/listView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/app_bar"
        />



</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: The issue is still not resolved. The last element can't be displayed perfectly.